# Reset state to initial value instead of most updated recent one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

As mentioned in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) during subsequent re-renders, the first value returned by `useState` will always be the most recent state after applying updates. However, I have a use case where the state needs to reinitialized to the initial value as provided in the props during subsequent re-renders.

Consider this example as a simplified version of my use case:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function Counter({ initialCount, handleChange }) {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(initialCount);

  const handleClick = (counter) => {
    setCount(count + counter);
    handleChange(count);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Counter {count}</h1>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => handleClick(1)}
        style={{ marginRight: "8px" }}
      >
        Add
      </button>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => handleClick(-1)}>
        Subtract
      </button>
    </>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [countOne, setCountOne] = React.useState(1);
  const [countTwo, setCountTwo] = React.useState(countOne % 2);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Counter
        initialCount={countOne}
        handleChange={(val) => setCountOne(val)}
      />
      <Counter
        initialCount={countTwo}
        handleChange={(val) => setCountTwo(val)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can check the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-wood-ggxk3?file=/src/App.js) as well.

When I increment the first counter I wish the second counter to be reset to 0 or 1 (from whatever state it was) depending on whether the count in the first counter is even or odd. Please note that there is only one-way dependency and not any circular one meaning; changing the count in the second counter should NOT reset the count in the first counter.

Comment: You could either use another state property, or `useRef` to create a value that will live throughout the lifespan of the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the react component docs

> If you want to **"reset" some state when a prop changes**, consider ... [fully uncontrolled with a key](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key) instead.

Use a react key on the component you want to reset to initial state of.

You can use `countOne` as the key for the second `Counter` you want to reset when the first `Counter` is updated. Provide `countOne % 2` as the initial value for the second `Counter`. Remove the duplicate state for `countTwo` as it's unnecessary. and make the `handleChange` callback optional, but pass the *new* state value to the callback, i.e. `count + counter`, or use an effect to handle that, otherwise the state values won't be in sync.

```
function Counter({ initialCount, handleChange }) {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(initialCount);

  const handleClick = (counter) => {
    setCount(count + counter);
    handleChange && handleChange(count + counter);
  };

  // or

  useEffect(() => {
    handleChange && handleChange(count);
  }, [count, handleChange]);

  const handleClick = (counter) => {
    setCount(count + counter);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Counter {count}</h1>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => handleClick(1)}
        style={{ marginRight: "8px" }}
      >
        Add
      </button>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => handleClick(-1)}>
        Subtract
      </button>
    </>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [countOne, setCountOne] = React.useState(1);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Counter
        initialCount={countOne}
        handleChange={setCountOne}
      />
      <Counter
        key={countOne}
        initialCount={countOne % 2}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit reset-state-to-initial-value-instead-of-most-updated-recent-one]

If you didn't want to use a react key to do the resetting to initial state then you can provide another prop to use as a dependency in a second `useEffect` hook to reset to the provided `initialValue` prop.

```
function Counter2({ initialCount, handleChange, reset }) {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(initialCount);

  useEffect(() => {
    handleChange && handleChange(count);
  }, [count, handleChange]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCount(initialCount);
  }, [reset, initialCount]);

  const handleClick = (counter) => {
    setCount(count + counter);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Counter 2: {count}</h1>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => handleClick(1)}
        style={{ marginRight: "8px" }}
      >
        Add
      </button>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => handleClick(-1)}>
        Subtract
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Pass `countOne` to the `reset` prop so the count is reset when `countOne` updates.

```
<Counter2 reset={countOne} initialCount={countOne % 2} />
```

Comment: Thank you. The only reason why I am not tempted to introduce a key here is it will force **re-create** the second `<Counter />` as `countOne` changes. Which seems to be an overkill for a state reset. I wonder if this could be done with `componentDidUpdate` in a class component.

Comment: @SibasishMohanty Well using a react key is a designed mechanism for reseting to *some* initial state. You could use `componentDidUpdate` in a class-based implementation, or add an `useEffect` with a dependency to reset. I updated the sandbox to include a second version of `Counter`, now `Counter1` and `Counter2`.